# Unable access Jupyter lab from Google Deep Learning VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, google-dl-platform

I am trying to open Jupyter Lab after installing Google Deep learning VM.

This code i am running in SSH terminal in browser:

```
export PROJECT_ID="name"
export ZONE="us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="tensorflow-1-vm"
gcloud compute ssh --project $PROJECT_ID --zone $ZONE \
  $INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

I always get same mistake and cannot access to http://localhost:8080/ :

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: for some reason Google Deep learning VM starts listening jupyter related ports automatically. I think this is related.  Can you do "sudo lsof -i " and lets see the ports

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your instance has firewall rules configure to allow http/https egress protocol along and the instance have a public IP.

Check this out https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/ssh-access